# Counting the number of times each cell appear in another column

Tags: postgresql

I have two columns:

```
year, birth_year
```

Now I want to create another column that counts how many was born that year. So for the year 1900, I want to look through the whole column of `birth_year` and count them all up, and then the same for the year 1901 and so on.

This seems so easy but it's driving me nuts.

//Mikael

Comment: `SELECT \`year\`, COUNT(DISTINCT birth_year) FROM my_table GROUP BY \`year\``

Comment: It doesn't seem to help. I get a long list of "1",

Comment: That means you have 1 distinct `birth_year` per each `year`. What other number do you expect and why?

Comment: I have a random generated column with birth_year. And then I want to know, for each year, how many that was born. Some years should be two, some 0 and so on.

Comment: Provide your dataset and expected result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `select year_, birth_year, birth_year+life_span as death_year

from
 (

select generate_series(1900, 2018) as year_,
round(random() * (1900-2000+1) + 2000)::int as birth_year,
round(random() * 90::int) as life_span

 )as temp

group by year_, birth_year, life_span
order by year_;`